# Would like to ask recommendation on giving a third-party an access to our API Endpoints

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, backend

We are planning to give our partners to have access to our APIs without them needed to create an account (Our accounts are targeted for clients).

I want to find a way to have a better approach for this.

What I plan is to create a Developer Service (AWS API Gateway + AWS Lambda + AWS Dynamo) that will allow our partners to register as a developer and create "apps".

We will give them "clientId" and "client secret" (or maybe "app secret")

Answer (score 0):

You could use [JWT](https://jwt.io/) (JSON Web Tokens) and give them an API key. This is a pretty standard mechanism and is very lightweight.

Comment: JWT token is for those who have an account right, am I right? Or is it possible to give/create a JWT token with account? Our partners won't have an account.

Comment: @Kokuou No, JWT is container for data. It allows everyone to read their content and let the person who knows the password verify whether the data has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

All depends is your partner can use API as client or not.

If only anonymous access you can add simple Auth based on API key and/or IP.

Otherwise standard is Oauth2 or combined solution.

Oauth2 is big system, that allow you and your users manage access.

In combined solution you can write your own simple Oauth2. Add table user-app when you store JWT tokens, that partner can use.

#### UPDATE (JWT)

In short: JWT is a token that contains data + signature + information about the validity of the token.

Most often there are user data, but no one can forbid you to enter your partner ID and permissions there.

The correct use of JWT allows you to relieve the database. I suggest you to use 2 JWT.

1 - long-term, which contains the partner's ID. After verifying the correctness of the token and whether the partner still has the rights, it is used to generate a short-term JWT token.

2 - short-term, which does not use the database to validate itself and retrieve permissions from the database, it is used for communication with the API

Comment: Our partners won't use the API as client. They will access different APIs. For Oauth2, it would require to create an account to our partners right?

Comment: I don't know Oauth2 enough, but it seems that it has its own structure, which you integrate with the current user database. But that the API will be with guest rights, better verification will be at the IP / api-key level (you have stored in the database, is the key valid and what you can do) or JWT (I will update the answer right away)